# Ubuntu won't start after upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Laptop was upgrading the most recent version while I was working and then shut off all of the sudden. When I rebooted it the login screen came up, but when I log in it brings me back to login. Initially running from a copy of Ubuntu on a USB drive allowed me to run advanced options, but the same thing happened. Now it won't go back to the advanced options no matter the number of reboots that I do when I set it to run off of USB.

What else can I try?

Comment: Hi, this time when you restart the system and at login screen try to click the cog wheel and select "Ubuntu on Wayland" Option. it is not a solution but just try at least if you can access your files.

Comment: :-( this is not an option